# Get a list of members with a Role | Discord.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, roles

So, I wanted to create a command like `.getuser @role` and the bot then tags every user with that role and after it says `x people have this role.`.

The problem is that I couldn't find anywhere something that resembles this, I hope someone will help me cause I'm out of luck on this one!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `roles.get()`

```js
members = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'role name').members.map(m=>m.user.tag);
```

Edit:
I've been received lots of messages claiming that the bot is inaccurately showing what members have what roles. This is because discord uses the cache to grab info about roles. To fix this do the following...

1. Navigate to your application at https://discord.com/developers/applications
2. Go to the bot section
3. Turn ON "Server Members Intent"

This will make it so that your discord bot doesn't grab from the cache for member data from the api.

Comment: Probably this is it, but I have no idea how to actually implement it, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Andrei Cristian TUDOR do you need help implementing it?

Comment: to be honest yeah, but I don't want to ask you for more, if you're totally fine with it I'd be really grateful but don't waste much time on it please

Comment: Ya just add me on discord `Levi_OP#1277` and its no problem. I have added like 15 people on discord just from helping people on stack excahnge

Answer (score 0):

```
let membersWithRole = guild.roles.resolve('role_ID').members.size
```

Basically we get a specific role from a guild trough its ID and then we see the size of the members collection of the role.

Comment: Well, that's just the last part of it, the actual problem is tagging everyone with that role and making your code modular for every rank, thanks for this anyway!

Comment: to tag everyone you can just loop trough the members collection and to make the code modular you can replace the `role_ID` with `message.mentions.roles.first()`